# Android Context Menu Options always added to all Context Menu's

Tags: android, contextmenu

I'm creating a basic Android project with Context Menu's for various Views on the Activity. I've created 4 different Context Menu options, 3 for different views on the screen and 1 for the Parent Layout.

The code is as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tV;
Button button;
CoordinatorLayout baseLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    tV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    baseLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.base_layout);

    registerForContextMenu(fab);
    registerForContextMenu(tV);
    registerForContextMenu(button);
    registerForContextMenu(baseLayout);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
    if (v.getId() == R.id.fab) 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_context_fab, menu);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.textView) {
        menu.add(v.getId(), 0, Menu.NONE, "Option 1");
        menu.add(v.getId(), 1, Menu.NONE, "Option 2");
        menu.add(v.getId(), 2, Menu.NONE, "Option 3");
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Setting Menu");
        menu.add(v.getId(), 0, Menu.NONE, "Setting 1");
        menu.add(v.getId(), 1, Menu.NONE, "Setting 2");
        menu.add(v.getId(), 2, Menu.NONE, "Setting 3");
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.base_layout) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Base Menu");
        menu.add(v.getId(), 0, Menu.NONE, "Preference 1");
        menu.add(v.getId(), 1, Menu.NONE, "Preference 2");
        menu.add(v.getId(), 2, Menu.NONE, "Preference 3");
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle().equals("Action 1")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Action 1 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (item.getTitle().equals("Action 2")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Action 2 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (item.getTitle().equals("Action 3")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Action 3 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (item.getGroupId() == R.id.textView) {
        if (item.getItemId() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Option 1 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Option 2 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Option 3 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if (item.getGroupId() == R.id.button) {
        if (item.getItemId() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Setting 1 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Setting 2 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Setting 3 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if (item.getGroupId() == R.id.base_layout) {
        if (item.getItemId() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Preference 1 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Preference 2 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Preference 3 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

This should create a different Context Menu in each case, however, whenever I long-press any View on the screen, the Menu Options for the Layout Context Menu (Preference Options) are also included in it.

For example, if I long press the Button, the Context Menu that pops-up contains:

```
Setting 1
Setting 2
Setting 3
Preference 1
Preference 2
Preference 3
```

I don't understand why my Layout Menu options are being added to all other Context Menu's

menu_content_fab.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context="com.osahub.rachit.contextmenu.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_1"
    android:title="Action 1"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_2"
    android:title="Action 2"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_3"
    android:title="Action 3"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Comment: What *should* happen when you click a button? Also please post menu_context_fab

Comment: When I long click on any view (fab, button, textView) the corresponding Context Menu should pop-up. When I long press on a location where no other view is located, the Context Menu for the BaseLayout should pop-up. However, the Context Menu for all views also contain the Base Layout menu items.